# JAX WS Server implementation performance issue for Linux JVM?

Tags: java, linux, performance, sockets, jax-ws

I've faced with a very weird problem. The built-in JAX WS server implementation works **100 times** slower on linux machines then on Mac OS X or Windows.

I've created and shared a JMH test: https://github.com/Andremoniy/linuxjvmjaxwstest

Basically it does the following:

- starts a JAX WS with one SOAP method:

  endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/", new FooServiceImpl());
- performs client requests to this method:

  String result = state.client.foo(state.foo);

On Mac OS X with 2 Cores Intel Core i7 it gives me:

```
# JMH version: 1.19
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_151, VM 25.151-b12
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
...
Result "test.openjdk.MyBenchmark.testMethod":
  3077.813 ±(99.9%) 51.818 ops/s [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (1718.347, 3077.813, 3315.271), stdev = 219.400
  CI (99.9%): [3025.995, 3129.630] (assumes normal distribution)

# Run complete. Total time: 00:06:49

Benchmark                Mode  Cnt     Score    Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testMethod  thrpt  200  3077.813 ± 51.818  ops/s
```

The same machine, docker without CPU limitations:

```
# JMH version: 1.19
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_151, VM 25.151-b12
# VM invoker: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/bin/java
...
Result "test.openjdk.MyBenchmark.testMethod":
  19.882 ?(99.9%) 0.169 ops/s [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (10.031, 19.882, 20.104), stdev = 0.715
  CI (99.9%): [19.714, 20.051] (assumes normal distribution)

# Run complete. Total time: 00:07:01

Benchmark                Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testMethod  thrpt  200  19.882 ? 0.169  ops/s
```

I've tried docker openjdk:8u151 as well as [OracleJava](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleJava). I've also tried to run it on VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04, on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance - on linux machines it is always around ~`20 ops/s`.

But when I change server implementation to Jetty:

```
    ContextHandlerCollection contextHandlerCollection = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    server.setHandler(contextHandlerCollection);

    JettyHttpServerProvider.setServer(server);
    HttpContext context = new JettyHttpServerProvider().createHttpServer(new InetSocketAddress(8888), 5).createContext("/");

    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(new MyBenchmark.FooServiceImpl());
    endpoint.publish(context);

    server.start();
```

the difference between performance on linux and other OS's disappears. That means that there is some bug in builtin HTTP Server implementation for JRE/OpenJDK for Linux. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see where it would enter the picture as you're not using SSL, but my guess is that it is an entropy issue. SecureRandom on Linux uses /dev/random which can block waiting for enough entropy. That doesn't happen on Windows, don't know about Mac. Try -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom and see if it helps!

Comment: @user2612030 I don't use SSL anywhere. I've tried `-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom` and it doesn't change anything. Please, refer my Github example, it is very simple.

Comment: Reported a bug for bugreport.java.com. An internal review ID : 9051777.

Comment: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
And this is for any random value.

Comment: @ThomasRS it doesn't change anything and I don't use any security or randomizer

Comment: No, but the framework might. Add a breakpoint in the right place and you'l see.

Comment: @ThomasRS I don't understand what do you mean. I've run the test with "-"-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom" and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was admitted as a bug by the Java Developer Support team:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193236